# Trying to compare lines of two variables in Bash Script

Tags: bash

I am writing a bash script and I have two variables

```
var1=$(ls -al .somedirectory | grep -E '...[someRegExp]...')
var2=$(ls -al .someOtherDirectory | grep -E '...[someOtherRegExp]...')
```

I am trying to get all lines uniquely in var1 and not in var2 at all. My initial guess was to try and utilize the `comm` command in the following fashion:

```
var3=$(echo $var1 | comm -23 $var2)
```

but this clearly does not work. I need var3 so that I can again iterate through the var3 in a for loop to edit file names but I have hit a road block. I would greatly appreciate any advice, pointers, or assistance as to how I can make a var3 as I have described. I can't just make a file and use it as one of the files for comm so I am looking for some other method...

Comment: Maybe a `grep -v -f` can help. Or `bash`'s process substitution to feed the data to the comparison program. (BTW, `comm` requires its input to be sorted)

Comment: Thank you, the process substitution was indeed the answer. The sort was indeed also necessary.

Comment: Also consider the need to quote your variables: `echo $var` versus `echo "$var"`